# how to plot a line chart with error values in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a time series stored in pandas DataFrame with columns low, average, and high. Currently, I plot the average values as a line chart, but I would like to fill the area between low and high values with a color.

I am hoping to create a chart that looks exactly like this

[image: example]

Comment: What have you tried? Anything that looks promising but you can't get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's something like:

```
ax.fill_between(df.index, df.upper, df.lower, where= df.upper > df.lower,
facecolor='red', alpha=0.5, interpolate=True)
```

Where ax is your axis, `df` is the `DataFrame` and `upper` and `lower` the bounds.